# how to add application/wasm mime type on debian localhost

Tags: localhost, mime-types

I need to attach application/wasm mime type on my debian localhost.For now firefox 59 doesn't allow me use webassembly examples giving me error in dev console

> TypeError: Response has unsupported MIME type

I remember that mime types are placed under /usr/share/mime*..
I tried to add alias application/wasm wasm but it doesn't help.
Advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround :

> 1. Flatten  previously downloaded webassembly studio project
> 2. Launch localserver with python3 -m http.server   (it has application/wasm support)